# Get last element from a list in an efficient way

Tags: haskell

What is the most efficient way to get the last element of a list in Haskell?

Example: `getLastElement [1,2,3,4]`should return `4`.

As far as I know, `last [1,2,3,4]` is not very efficient as Haskell digs through the list which results in an efficiency of `O(n)` where `n`is the length of the list.

Comment: There is no other way of doing that because of how list is built.

Answer (score 11):

Okasaki's book teaches us a nice trick for adding efficient APIs to existing data structures: wrap up the structure in a new one that caches the result of the API calls. If you *only* want to add `last` to the set of efficient calls, here's the simple way to do that:

```
import Control.Monad -- mplus is a convenient spell

data LastList a = LastList
    { forget :: [a]
    , last   :: Maybe a
    }

nil = LastList [] Nothing
cons x l = LastList (x : forget l) (last l `mplus` Just x)
```

Now the `last` operation is O(1), easy-cheesy. This is very limited: you can't *modify* the end of the list efficiently, or get the second-to-last element efficiently, or build one of these out of a list efficiently (so you have to replace all list-based functions with these guys through your whole code to see the benefit), or anything like that, but the one call you asked to be efficient is.

Answer (score 10):

Note first that `last` is not particularly great on other grounds, since it is a partial function like `head`.  If you are constantly using the tail end of the list, scrap it for `Data.Sequence` or `Data.Vector.Unboxed`:

```
import Data.Sequence

firstThing seq = case viewl seq of
   EmptyL -> error "no beginning"
   a :< as -> a

lastThing seq = case viewr seq of
   EmptyR -> error "no end"
   as :> a -> a

-- > lastThing (fromList "abc")
-- 'c'
-- > firstThing (fromList "abc")
-- 'a'
```

If you are using an unboxed type like `Int`, `Double`, `Char` etc. then you will get still better results with `Data.Vector.Unboxed` , see the documentation for remarks about the efficiency of `Data.Vector.Unboxed.head` and `Data.Vector.Unboxed.last` http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.10.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#g:4

In the special case where you are using lists of `Char`s use `Data.Text` wherever possible, this is *emphatically* the 'idiomatic' thing.  Again see the documentation for `head` and `last` http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.2.3/doc/html/Data-Text.html

If you are imagining a contrast between 'Haskell' lists and 'lists' in other languages, it is probably the contrast between 'Haskell' lists on the one hand, and vectors and arrays on the other; the latter are just as 'Haskelly' as lists.

Answer (score 9):

That is it with the list data structure right? If you want the last element, you will have `O(n)` complexity. There is no going around that.

You will have to consider a different data structure like [`Data.Sequence`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Sequence.html)

Answer (score 1):

With the built in list there is no way around O(n) complexity (you can only get the first element, and the rest of the list every time so you can't get to the end without going through all n elements).